# WS02 identity server user session endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I searched for wso2is 5.9 apis, I did not find any form of session information for a user.

What would be the way to extract a user's session information, to know if a user is active or inactive or has a valid session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 IS 5.9.0 release includes the REST API to retrieve this API as an end-user only. You can find the API documentation from [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/session-mgt-rest-api/).

However, the IS 5.10.0 release contains the REST API to retrieve session information as an administrative user as well. API documentation can be found [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/develop/session-mgt-rest-api/).